# Multiple EditTexts cause NullPointerException in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have encountered a problem when developing my Android application.  When I try to retrieve values of multiple `EditText`s, I encounter a NullPointerException.  Here's what I have:

```
 public void next(View v) {

    View view = (View)v.getParent();
    MeditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MeditText.getText().toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddManually2.this, DatabaseFiller.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
01-28 19:22:31.663  20042-20042/com.example.foodsaver2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.foodsaver2, PID: 20042
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at com.example.foodsaver2.AddManually2.next(AddManually2.java:133)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I changed the code to this:

```
MeditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

which is without the `view.findViewById` worked.  That produced no errors.  I am trying to retrieve all the `EditText` values.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: EditText inside a ListView is highly discouraged since it causes a lot of focus issues. You should consider having different interactions.

Comment: have you declared MeditText as an EditText?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma Yes, I have `EditText MeditText;` in my activity/class

Comment: I am confused by the wording of your question. You said, "When I changed the code to this: ...which is without view.findViewById worked" Then you said "that produced no errors"...if it produces not errors then what is the problem?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma Ok, right now, I have `view.findViewById`, which gets all the edittexts.  This crashes the app.  When I change this part to just `findViewById`, which gets only one edittext, it works.  I want to get all of the edittexts, therefore, I need `view.findViewById`